# package expl3 Version 2018/02/21 not installed after update with TeX Live Utility

Tags: expl3

Dear Ladies and Gentlemen,

After updating TeX Live with the TeX Live Utility, today, XeLaTeX does not compile any file any more, and gives in the console the warnings:  “package expl3 Version 2018/02/21 not installed”, and “Package xparse Error: Support package l3kernel too old” and says: “Please install up to date version of l3kernel using your tex package manager from CTAN“.
It seems that with the new update something which has to be updated also has not been updated. Does anyone know what to do?

With best regards,
Jens Bakker

Comment: Wait until tomorrow and install then l3kernel or revert l3package to the previous version.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416862/lualatex-stopped-working-in-texlive-2017

Comment: Dear Ulrike Fischer and dear Christian Hupfer, thank you very much for the answer, Jens Bakker

Comment: I have a spare computer that fortunately had versions of the packages l3build, l3experimental, l3kernel, and l3packages that are a few days old and don't have the problem many people are experiencing today. You're welcome to download this zip file and paste the enclosed four packages/folders into your "texmf-dist\tex\latex" folder if you don't want to wait for CTAN and tlmgr to get sorted. I did this to get my primary computer able to compile again just a few minutes ago. Hope this helps. Link below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/snnjam16gom1c40/l3packages.zip?dl=0

Comment: Dear Tim Stewart, thank you very much for proposing this solution, I have tried it and it works fine. Thank you very much for your effort, Jens Bakker

Comment: By the way, there is a new update with l3kernel etc. which I have updated after using the method of Tim Stewart which enabled LaTeX  once more, and it did not work again, so I followed the instruction of Tim Steward a second time and the functionality was restored.

Comment: @JensBakker Glad I could help! Happy TeXing!